# Why is my regex replacing more than I want it to?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Here's a string example: "This is a     \n\n\nTest"

This is the code I'm using

```
import re

def split_text_into_sentences(text):
    text = re.sub(r'\s+\n', '\n', text)
    return text

print([split_text_into_sentences('This is a     \n\n\nTest')])
```

For some reason, I'm getting

```
['This is a\nTest']
```

But I'm expecting

```
['This is a\n\nTest']
```

I thought \s+\n would only get rid of the first \n with at least one white space character before it, but for some reason, the rest of the \n's get replace too. Could someone explain why? Thanks!

Comment: `\n` is a whitespace character too.

Answer (score 1):

`\s` includes `\n` as well:

> \s
>
> For Unicode (str) patterns:
> Matches Unicode whitespace characters (which includes `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`, and also many other characters, for example the non-breaking spaces mandated by typography rules in many languages). If the ASCII flag is used, only `[ \t\n\r\f\v]` is matched.
>
> For 8-bit (bytes) patterns:
> Matches characters considered whitespace in the ASCII character set; this is equivalent to `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`.
>
> — https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

So you might want to use `r' +\n'` instead. Even in that case, however, the result would have three `\n`s, *not* `This is a\n\nTest`. If the latter is not a typo and you indeed intend this, the second argument of `re.sub()` should be `''`.

Comment: he is using end-line only.